# NextJs fetch makes https call with http url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

As seen in the picture i try fetching url and for some reason my NextJs application changes `http` to `https` before fetching.

If i go manually to that url with `http://...` in incognito tab it does work and fetch data.

What can I do so inside react next js app it does not go to `https` but stays at `http`?

This is code I use to fetch api, however for testing purpose I changed `${baseUrl}${endpoint}` with my url which can be seen in picture.

```
export const fetchApi = (apiBase: ApiBase, endpoint: string) => {
    
    const { publicRuntimeConfig } = getConfig()
    let baseUrl: string;

    if(apiBase == null)
        throw new Error(`Parameter 'apiBase' is required!`)

    switch(apiBase) {
        case ApiBase.Main:
            baseUrl = publicRuntimeConfig.API_BASE_URL_MAIN
            break;
        default:
            throw new Error(`Unhandled ApiBase!`)
    }

    return new Promise<IResponse>((resolve, reject) => {
        fetch(`${baseUrl}${endpoint}`).then((response) => {
            if(response.status == 200) {
                response.json().then((apiResponseObject) => {
                    resolve(apiResponseObject)
                })
            }
        }).catch((reason) => {
            reject(reason)
        })
    })
}
```

Also I have added `redirect: 'error'` and I can see I get `307 Internal Redirect`

Somewhere I found that NexJs can't communicate with `http` only `https`, but not sure if that is the case.

[image]

Comment: Can you share your full code, and how you call it ?

Comment: @HamudeShahin I have edited and added the code